# Quais as formas de medir o conhecimento de um programador?

Tags: metodologia

Assim como existem técnicas para medir a produtividade, existe técnica ou formas para medir o conhecimento de um programador (tanto numa tecnologia específica quanto no geral)?

Se sim, quais? Na programação existem níveis de conhecimento (Ex: Sou Programador Pleno C#, devo saber implementar **x** na linguagem)? Existe uma linearidade nisso ou é possível pular passos?

Seria uma forma de avaliar um programador aplicando uma prova baseado no cargo que ele vai exercer e quais ferramentas e tecnologias ele vai trabalhar? *(com a finalidade de saber se ele vai atingir os objetivos propostos, sem auxílio externo como **Google**, saber o conhecimento real dele).*

Comment: Eu entendo que é uma pergunta com o intuito **técnico**, mas, eu acredito, que seja muito fácil ela se direcionar por um caminho subjetivo, já que o conhecimento (por si só) já é algo bastante subjetivo. De qualquer forma, acho que o caminho será portfólio + certificados + testes de conhecimento.

Comment: A resposta é subjetiva. Até onde sei, não há um conjunto critério para medição universal, assim como ocorrem nas provas de proficiências em inglês (TOEFL, IELTS). E mesmo assim, essas provas tem a cobrança subjetiva e focos diferentes (negócios, acadêmicos, etc). Acredito que portfólio indique mais experiência do que nível de conhecimento, pelo que já vi acontecer diversas vezes.
Testes de conhecimento + certificados é um caminho. Mas não devem ser levados em conta para comparação de conhecimento de programadores.

Comment: Provavelmente testes. Vão me jogar pedras por dizer isto, mas certificados e diplomas estão longe de indicar conhecimento verdadeiro. Academia é ótimo até o sujeito sentar na cadeira e enfrentar um problema real com prazo real e que envolva um misto de situações que já não é o ideal desde o princípio. Bons testes têm uma maior chance de refletir o perfil do programador.

Comment: Publicar 10 perguntas e 10 respostas no SOzão e não receber **nenhum** downvote == grau razoável. Os upvotes vão medir o grau OK++ :D

Comment: Acredito que valha um debate sobre o assunto. Sembre gostei do tema. Inclusive trabalhei em uma empresa onde os cargos eram bem definidos em 7 níveis para desenvolvedor. Sabia-se o que se esperava de cada cargo e a única coisa que foi possível fazer para avaliar eram Testes. Utilizávamos coaching para acompanhar o crescimento e ajudar a adquirir conhecimento. Se houver um debate sobre o tema, gostaria de participar

Comment: @Caputo Eu concordo em fazer a discussão, e postei uma pergunta [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1487/sobre-a-nossa-propria-tolerancia-aos-limites-do-que-e-on-topic) que talvez ajude a iniciá-la. :)

Comment: Nada como por o dito programador a programar, ai sim se vê a qualidade :)

Comment: abri a votação para reabrir, acho que está concisa agora.

Comment: [Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no **meta**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1487).

Comment: IMO a única métrica válida para medir conhecimento do programador é a quantidade de vezes porminuto que você exclama "que porra é essa" ao revisar seu código.

Answer (score 4):

No Brasil, e especificamente no âmbito acadêmico, existe uma prova unificada (isto é, aplicada em todo o território nacional - e em alguns países vizinhos, como o Peru) chamada [Exame Nacional para Ingresso na Pós-Graduação em Computação (POSCOMP)](http://www.sbc.org.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=237&Itemid=182).

Esse exame é organizado pela [Sociedade Brasileira de Computação (SBC)](http://www.sbc.org.br/) e tem por objetivo avaliar os candidatos a programas de pós-graduação no país. O teste avalia conhecimento em três campos - matemática, fundamentos de computação (teoria) e tecnologia de computação (sistemas e aplicações) - distribuídos em 70 questões de múltipla escolha. Os assuntos abordados fazem parte do currículo de Ciência da Computação das principais universidades e faculdades brasileiras, e por isso não avaliam o autor em uma tecnologia específica, mas como uma forma de conhecimento geral (muito embora é comum cair no campo de tecnologia questões sobre SQL, sintaxe de linguagens como C++ e Java, etc).

Os candidatos não são "aprovados" ou "reprovados" no teste. Eles recebem individualmente (não há uma tabela geral de classificação) sua avaliação em termos da pontuação obtida (acertos por campo) em comparação com a média e desvio padrão do país. Creio que vale por um ano (até a realização da próxima prova), mas não achei essa informação no site pra confirmar. O resultado individual não é obrigatório em muitas das universidades, servindo apenas como um critério adicional para a seleção dos candidatos. Também não tenho informações a respeito de seu uso em outros contextos.

> O exame é considerado bastante difícil, tendo como média pouco mais de
>   30% de acerto em suas questões (fonte:
>   [Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poscomp)).

Comment: Considero esta prova como medição de conhecimento geral e não específico. Além de quê como está mesmo escrito "tem por objetivo avaliar os candidatos a programas de pós-graduação". E quem não está interessado e não quer fazer pós? Seria ponto negativo, por assim dizer? No meio acadêmico, em especial, como é descrito logo no início, seria interessante, mais para o mercado de trabalho não contaria como algo que medisse o profissional.

Comment: @LeoFelipe Bom, o teste poderia ser utilizado por empresas para avaliar profissionais de uma forma similar ao que o TOEFL faz para o nível de inglês, se alguém assim desejasse. Mas realmente acho pouquíssimo provável que isso um dia ocorra. De todas as formas, ele é uma forma de avaliação que existe e é utilizada, ainda que em um contexto específico. Apenas deixei isso claro na resposta. Aliás, a pergunta também não limitou contexto, então...

Comment: Sim @Luiz Vieira, poderia, mas acho que seria trabalho em vão. Pois o ponto chave da pergunta é "Quais as formas de medir o conhecimento de um ***programador***?". Isso torna algo já específico para uma empresa, já que ela vai querer contratar um programador de algumas determinadas tecnologias que ele trabalhará, tipo S#+Sqlserver+javascript, ou php+mysql+jquery, ou ZF2+oracle. Normalmente as procuras pela empresa são assim. Então seria mais proveitoso, ao meu ver, pedir o link do GitHub e visualizar o histórico dos códigos do candidato do que a nota do POSCOMP(sem tirar seu mérito, é claro).

Comment: @LeoFelipe O seu argumento a respeito da especificidade para a indústria é justo (ainda assim as notas do campo "tecnologia" no teste poderiam ser úteis na indústria - mas bobagem insistir nessa argumentação). De todas as formas, **programador** não é só aquele que trabalha na indústria. A academia muitas vezes também busca pessoas com qualificações específicas e a sua própria resposta (sobre a avaliação com o GitHub) é algo que se faz lá também com frequência (na seleção de projetos específicos). Assim, acho que o interesse aqui no SOPT vale pra ambos os mundos. :)

Comment: Claro @Luiz Vieira estamos em consenso. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Além de certificados de conclusão de cursos, certificações etc um teste solicitando exemplos de código em um ambiente sem acesso a Internet :) ...
Mas além de conhecimento técnico outras qualidades devem ser levadas em conta, como capacidade de trabalhar em equipe, ética, disciplina etc.
Já vi excelentes técnicos, mas canalhas, só falando assim....

Comment: Concordo com a parte de certificados, mas em 80% dos casos os entrevistadores falham ao desenvolver um "exercício" que realmente possa medir a capacidade do candidato

Comment: Por isso, @Mota, este "exercício" atualmente tem sido feito analisando o histórico do GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

O que tem acontecido muito hoje em dia é saber o quê e como o programador programa. Ou seja, ver os projetos open source que ele contibuio, atualmente é utilizado muito o GitHub para analisar essa parte. Desta forma dá pra se ter uma idéia de como ele resolve os problemas lógicos de um problema e o nível do seu código e do paradigma usado.

Além disso, é claro, certificações, cursos, tempo de experiência com determinada tecnologia. E também a parte de RH que é muito difícil identificar em entrevistas, pois muitos candidatos nem sempre falam a verdade sobre seu comportamento no ambiente de trabalho.